# Serve 2 flask web apps with different templates and static folder locations to one NGINX server block

Tags: nginx, flask

I am serving a Flask app via NGINX using the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    # server name
    server_name mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
    
    location /my_subdomain {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
       proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/;
     }
     
     location /templates/ {
        alias /path/to/templates/;
     }

     location /static/  {
        alias /path/to/static/;
     }
}
```

which works pretty smoothly.

However, when I try to add one more app, with different templates and static files path, I can not fathom how to modify properly the NGINX server block.

I have tried the following without any success:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate     /path/to/pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

# server name
server_name mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;

location /my_subdomain {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/;

   location /my_subdomain/templates/ {
     alias /path/to/sub_domain/templates/;
   }

   location /my_subdomain/static/  {
     alias /path/to/sub_domain/static/;
   }
 }

location /my_subdomain2 {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/;

   location /my_subdomain2/templates/ {
     alias /path/to/sub_domain2/templates/;
   }

   location /my_subdomain2/static/  {
     alias /path/to/sub_domain2/static/;
   }
 }}
```

Do anyone have any clue on how to modify NGINX server block in order to serve both apps?